# How to make sphinx look for modules in virtualenv while building html?

Tags: virtualenv, python-sphinx

I want to build html docs using a virtualenv instead of the native environment on my machine.

I've entered the virtualenv but when I run `make html` I get errors saying the module can't be imported - I *know* the errors are due to the module being unavailable in my native environment. 
How can I specify which environment should be used when searching for docs (eg the virtualenv)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The problem here is that `make html` uses the `sphinx-build` command as a normal shell command, which explicitly specifies which Python interpreter to use in the first line of the file (ie. `#!/usr/bin/python`). If Python gets invoked in this way, it will not use your virtual environment.

A quick and dirty way around this is by explicitly calling the `sphinx-build` Python script from an interpreter. In the `Makefile`, this can be achieved by changing `SPHINXBUILD`  to the following:

```
SPHINXBUILD   = python <absolute_path_to_sphinx-build-file>/sphinx-build
```

If you do not want to modify your `Makefile` you can also pass this parameter from the command line, as follows:

```
make html SPHINXBUILD='python <path_to_sphinx>/sphinx-build'
```

Now if you execute `make build` from within your VirtualEnv environment, it should use the Python interpreter from within your environment and you should see Sphinx finding all the goodies it requires.

I am well aware that this is not a neat solution, as a `Makefile` like this should not assume any specific location for the `sphinx-build` file, so any suggestions for a more suitable solution are warmly welcomed.

Comment: You can use the [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) to avoid hardcoding the absolute path: ``SPHINXBUILD = python $(shell which sphinx-build)``

Comment: I'd rather suggest `SPHINXBUILD = python -m sphinx` (as of Sphinx 1.4.5 it is the same), which is more portable across make and avoid a subshell.

Comment: This answer saved me. Thanks! I just wanted to add that it works fine within `scl` as well, like this: `scl enable python27 'make html SPHINXBUILD=/nfs/tools/lib/python/2.7/current/bin/sphinx-build'`

Comment: worked for me too, from within a virtualenv, with a globally installed Sphinx.  Txs!

Comment: @ento and @bufh Both of these solutions leave me with an error saying `No module named 'sphinx'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much. This saved the day for me. I activated the venv, and installed sphinx in there, so my command line to build is `make html SPHINXBUILD='../venv/bin/python3.8 ../venv/bin/sphinx-build'`.  I was stumped for the whole morning until I found this post.  Honestly, how frustrating! None of the Sphinx HOWTO pages mentioned this at all. I'd take you for a beer if it were not for the pandemic.

Comment: In other words, if the shebang is fixed in `sphinx-build` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` the issue goes away...

Answer (score 70):

The problem is correctly spotted by Mathijs.

```
$ which sphinx-build
/usr/local/bin/sphinx-build
```

I solved this issue installing sphinx itself in the virtual environment.

With the environment activated:

```
$ source /home/migonzalvar/envs/myenvironment/bin/activate
$ pip install sphinx
$ which sphinx-build
/home/migonzalvar/envs/myenvironment/bin/sphinx-build
```

It seems neat enough.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution by far -- no hacking Makefiles etc. required. Should be the accepted solution, IMHO.

Comment: This isn't going to work if you have created your virtual environment with access to the global packages and you have a global Sphinx installation.

Comment: a) it didn't work.  b) I don't want to pollute a production `requirements.txt` with something as heavy as sphinx.  as per Mathijs `make html SPHINXBUILD='python <path_to_sphinx>/sphinx-build'`  where I got the path from `which sphinx-build`.  Now, when I say *didn't work*, might be because sphinx was already in global pip, dunno.  So, *this should be accepted* is highly subjective.

Comment: This works for me and is indeed neat enough. @JLPeyret putting it in your virtual env does not necessarily imply to put it in the `requirements.txt` (I mean it's worth not putting it to be able not to change makefile to make this work)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I couldn't use the accepted solution because I didn't use the Makefile. I was calling `sphinx-build` from within a custom python build file. What I really wanted to do was to call `sphinx-build` with the exact same environment that I was calling my python build script with. Fiddling with paths was too complicated and error prone, so I ended up with what seems to me like an elegant solution, which is to "manually" load the console script entry point and call it:

```py
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
cmd = load_entry_point('Sphinx', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-build')
cmd(['sphinx-build', basepath, destpath])
```